# Install Android apps in Kindle fire with Jelly Bean 4.1

Tags: applications, google-play-store, amazon-kindle

I upgrade my Kindle Fire with Android Jelly Bean 4.1 but i can't install some apps from Google Play site, it mentions that they are not compatible with the device, the only solution now would be install apk's manually? or depends on `AndroidManifest.xml` configuration set in every app?

Answer (score 1):

The kindle fire does not support Google Play or Jelly Bean. I would guess that is the root of your problem. You are trying to run an application that doesn't work on a device with an OS that it wasn't meant to run.

Edit: If you are attempting to install them via the market web page front end then you are only doing the latter of the above. Either way though the official Market does not support the Kindle Fire, you have to use amazons app store. Which I suspect also may not work since you installed an unsupported OS on your device.

Comment: There're AOSP build with working gapps for the Kindle fire.

Answer (score 0):

Kindle fire doesn't have phone support, camera support, maps and also some few hardware support. So when your are trying to install those apps It will show

```
“your device isn't compatible with this version”
```

**Solution:** Look for apps which are supported by the Kindle Fire and then you can download it via Amazon store or Google Play.

Comment: You can read how to fake an IMEI to fix the phone part of the fire [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1436486) , maybe there's also a way to add the phone subsystem requirements for Google Play (fake them). More threads [here (supported devices)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1570260) and [here (original dev thread)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1103766)

Comment: Info: It basically patches framework.jar and injects a hardcoded IMEI value into it.

Comment: Filtering is determined by comparing device configurations. only IMEI wont do all.

Comment: Yep, that's right. The above mentioned fix only adresses null pointer exeptions and such for some apps (after one changed his device configuration)